# How to setup Ctags for Sublime Text 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext, sublimetext3, ctags

I'm using the Sublime Text 3 with Ruby On Rails projects.

Some time ago, I setup CTags using [this tutorial](http://thunderboltlabs.com/blog/2013/11/19/efficiency-with-sublime-text-and-ruby/).

It was fine, but suddenly stopped to work. I'm getting the following error when try to rebuild the tags of project.

**/bin/sh: ctags_for_ruby: command not found**

These are my files:

/usr/local/bin/ctags_for_ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
system "find . -name '*.rb' | ctags -f .tags -L -"

if File.exist? './Gemfile'
  require 'bundler'
  paths = Bundler.load.specs.map(&:full_gem_path).join(' ')
  system "ctags -R -f .gemtags #{paths}"
end
```

~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/CTags.sublime-settings

```
{
    "debug"           :  false,
    "autocomplete": false,
    "command"   :  "ctags_for_ruby",
    "filters"         :  {
        "source.python": {"type":"^i$"}
    },
    "definition_filters": {
        "source.php": {"type":"^v$"}
    },
    "definition_current_first": true,
    "show_context_menus": true,
    "extra_tag_paths" :  [ [["source.python", "windows"], "C:\\Python27\\Lib\\tags"]],
    "extra_tag_files" : [".gemtags", ".tags"]
}
```

And the `$PATH` variable includes `/usr/local/bin` directory.

Why Sublime can't find/execute the `ctags_for_ruby` file?

Comment: Have you installed package control yet?

Comment: Yes, @MarcoPrins, as said, the installation was working and stopped

Comment: @rodrigo ST3 comes with "go to definition" feature, are there any other specific advantages of still using Ctags in ST3 that I'm missing? If yes, kindly elaborate. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that "go to definition" knows anything about your gems @boddhisattva

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/usr/local/bin` may be in your shell's `$PATH`, but it is not getting picked up by Sublime. To fix this, edit `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/CTags.sublime-settings` and change the `"command"` setting to `"/usr/local/bin/ctags_for_ruby"`. Also, unless you are using the system Ruby in `/usr/bin`, you might want to edit the first line of `/usr/local/bin/ctags_for_ruby` from `#/usr/bin/env ruby` to the direct path of your Ruby interpreter - you can find this by running `which ruby` on the command line.

Comment: I have a question regarding Ctags with sublime. Do you build tags every time you build the project? I am running it on windows 7

Comment: @UnderDog I'd recommend [asking a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/ask). I personally don't use CTags.